# Keyup method for ckeditor not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I have a ckeditor textarea instance that changes based on a category selection.
Whenever the user changes the category, an ajax call will be launch and the CKEditor instance will be populated via the returned value. What I want is to display total no words inserted by the user (via typing directly or thru AJAX call).

This is what I've tried although the CKEditor's `keyup` method is not working:

```
$(document).on('keyup',e, function() {
    $('#articleLength')
        .val(CKEDITOR
            .instances
            .keywords
            .getData()
            .replace(/<[^>]*>|\s/g, '')
            .length);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you want to fire keyup event when a use is writing in ckeditor?